# Fetch data that don't exist in pivot table column - Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables viz

```
1. users
columns: id, name

2. user_access
columns: id, user_id, user_access_id
```

`user access` is a pivot table that defines the relationship between `users` table and `users` table itself. For example, a user might have access to data of some other users.

I have defined this relationship in `User` model.

Now I want to fetch those user ids for a user which don't exist in `user_access` table.
For example, a user may have access to id 1 & 2 but he doesn't have access to id 3 & 4, so I want to fetch id 3 & 4 and not 1 & 2.

To achieve this I use whereDoesntHave eloquent but it's not working for relationship on the same tables and I get the following error

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::getRelated() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\prd_tracker\resources\views\tracker\ticket\script.blade.php)
```

but it does work for different tables.

Here is my code

**User Model**

```
public function userAccess()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_access', 'user_id', 'user_access_id')->using('App\USER_ACCESS');
    }
```

**Logic**

```
use App\User;

        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        //Get All Those Users Ids Which Does Not Belong To Auth User
        $exception_user_ids = User::whereDoesntHave('users', function ($query) use($user_id) {
          $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
        })
        ->pluck('id');
```

Comment: if A access user B, B is access_user_id or A?

Answer (score 0):

The error may be in the `User` model.

The `App\User` model cannot `belongsToMany()` of itself...`App\User`.

I believe you may need a `UserAccess` model.

Try:

**User Model**

```
public function userAccess()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\UserAccess', 'user_access', 'user_id', 'user_access_id')
}
```

or try a `hasMany` relationship:

**User Model**

```
public function userAccess()
{   
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserAccess', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many